# Redirecting www to non-www for custom URI

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect non-www to www .And Also I am using custom url where `domain.com/blablabla.html` must show content of **url.php** ..

I use below code and where `domain.com/blablabla.html` is showing content of `url.php` but when I access `www.domain.com/blablabla.html` its redirecting to `domain.com/url.php` , Instead It must redirect to `domain.com/blablabla.html` and show content of `url.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ /url.php [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip the order of your rules otherwise last rules only works on converted URI:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+\.html$ /url.php [L,NC]
```

Don't forget to clear your browser cache before testing this.